# Is this character from Isle of Dogs an homage to Ran, or just a coincidence?

Tags: reference, isle-of-dogs, ran

In the first scene of the movie [*Isle of Dogs* (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Dogs_(film)) by Wes Anderson, there is a character that looks exactly like Lord Hidetora Ichimonji from the movie [*Ran* (1985)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ran_(film)) by Akira Kurosawa.

Here are the two characters side by side:

[image: comparison]

Having just watched *Ran* a few months ago and giving the distinctive looks of Lord Hidetora, I immediately noticed the similarities between the two characters. The resemblance is uncanny so I doubt it's unintentional. Maybe it is an homage by the filmmakers to the iconic movie *Ran* by the iconic director Kurosawa.

**Are there any official statements by the filmmakers that prove/disprove this connection?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Vulture](http://www.vulture.com/2018/03/unpacking-the-akira-kurosawa-references-in-isle-of-dogs.html), Yes.

Although this specific scene is not mentioned, *Ran* and other Kurosawa's works are and therefore it is likely the case.

> **Anderson remained mum back in Berlin when questioned as to how, exactly, Kurosawa’s work figures into Isle of Dogs. But even on the
>   first watch, a viewer is smacked right in the face with a panoramic
>   visual grandeur that could only belong to the painterly master of yore
>   — just rendered on an itsy-bitsy scale. Some of the references are
>   more Easter egg-ish and some have been integrated into the general
>   fabric of the film, but either way, Kurosawa’s all over the place.**
>   For the benefit of the casual viewing public, Vulture has made five
>   selections from his extensive filmography that most closely inform
>   Isle of Dogs, as a pre- or post-viewing companion to this worthy
>   homage. Now strike up the taiko drums and read on...

And also stated here:

> **Isle of Dogs also pays a good deal of homage to Kurosawa’s period-set
>   films as well.** The score for Seven Samurai is heard on the soundtrack
>   at one point (as is the score for Drunken Angel), and the same movie
>   gets some shot-for-shot reference too — **for details on that and its
>   tributes to Throne of Blood, Ran, and more**, Vulture has a great guide
>   to the Kurosawa Easter eggs. Stray Dog is also discussed there. But
>   some eggs are likely still hidden given what Anderson said during a
>   masterclass Q&A last year: “The reason to hide your [inspirations] is
>   because you’re trying to steal them, and if you can sneak them in then
>   you’ve gained something without having to lose something.”
>   https://filmschoolrejects.com/movies-to-watch-isle-of-dogs/

And a bit more of a confirmation from [Indiewire](https://www.indiewire.com/2017/03/wes-anderson-isle-of-dogs-akira-kurosawa-inspiration-1201793120/):

> As for the second source of inspiration: It’s none other than Akira
>   Kurosawa. The director has never been one to shy away from his
>   admiration for Kurosawa, **and he teased that “Isle Of Dogs” will be a
>   full blown homage to the Japanese icon. “The new film is less
>   influenced by stop-motion movies than it is by Akira Kurosawa,”
>   Anderson confirmed.**